# Passing Button name between pages windows phone 8

Tags: c#, string, button, windows-phone-8

I need a little help passing a button name/value to another page. Example
Page one has a button with name "Button 1".
Page two has a public string called "Passed-button-name".
When a user press a button one in page one, The string value in page will be same as the button name.
How will i go about creating this??
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use query string parameter for string variable like below :

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml?key=value", Urikind.Relative));

To get it on the target page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("key"))
    {
         string val = NavigationContext.QueryString["key"];
    }
}
```

Comment: One little problem, NavigationContext is not recognized

Comment: Did you add this namespace? using System.Windows.Navigation;